# How to display full width homepage static blocks magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have added cms block and catalog product widget in homepage so now i just need to make those section as full width . How can I achieve it

Comment: cms block call using xml file ??? And check your homepage layout ...

Comment: @MohitPatel no add cms blocks using Logged into backend content/pages/homepage inside hoepage i have added cms blocks

Comment: check homepage layout

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in  Layout Update XML of CMS page for which you want.

```
<referenceContainer name="main.content" htmlTag="main" htmlClass="page-main-full-width" />
```

Please find the screenshot for your reference.

[image]

Comment: lastest magento version we cant use like this in design

Comment: How to do in cms block, i just added my cms block into cms page. I can't give to cms page because more than one cms block available, how to do in cms block?